# What does it mean when an HTTP request returns status code 0?

Tags: ajax, http, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse, fetch-api

What does it mean when JavaScript network calls such as fetch or XMLHttpRequest, or any other type of HTTP network request, fail with an HTTP status code of 0?

This doesn't seem to be a valid HTTP status code as other codes are three digits in HTTP specification.

I tried unplugging the network completely as a test. It may be unrelated, but that resulted in status code 17003 (IIRC), which cursory searching suggests means "DNS server lookup failed".

The same code works fine from some locations and systems, however within certain environments it fails with status code 0 and there is no responseText provided.

This is a typical HTTP POST to an Internet URL. It does not involve file:// which I understand may return 0 indicating success in Firefox.

Comment: Could it be due to firewall? What OS is your client running the app on?

Comment: Might be Useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12622082/386579

Comment: Related post - [What does HTTP status code 0 mean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19858251/465053)

Comment: I've had the same problem in Firefox and found out that an ad blocker plugin prevents all requests to URLs that contain the word `banner`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an HTTP Status code of 0 have any meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I believe the error code indicates that the response was empty, (as not even headers were returned). This means the connection was accepted and then closed gracefully (TCP FIN).
There are a number of things which could cause this, but based off of your description, some form of firewall seems the most likely culprit.

Comment: I think you are probably right. (Although, as pointed out by @sleepycod wininet.dll would be expected to return some status code in the absence of a _real_ http status code.)

Comment: This is not necessarily correct. I've had the same problem, but in my case, a request was never sent. The reason was that a Firefox ad blocker prevented requests whose URLs contain the word `banner`

Comment: Wrong.  There are three classes of errors which you will get a status=0.  Those are abort, timeout, and error.  The first two are self explanatory.  Error indicates a network level error occurred and from experience, it is usually recorded in the console.

Answer (score 255):

**Many of the answers here are wrong.**  It seems people figure out what was causing status==0 in their particular case and then generalize that as the answer.

**Practically speaking, status==0 for a failed XmlHttpRequest should be considered an undefined error.**

The actual W3C spec defines the conditions for which zero is returned here:
   https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-network-error

As you can see from the spec (fetch or XmlHttpRequest) this code could be the result of an error that happened even before the server is contacted.

Some of the common situations that produce this status code are reflected in the other answers but it could be any or none of these problems:

1. Illegal cross origin request  (see [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing))
2. Firewall block or filtering
3. The request itself was cancelled in code
4. An installed browser extension is mucking things up

What would be helpful would be for browsers to provide detailed error reporting for more of these status==0 scenarios.  Indeed, sometimes status==0 will accompany a helpful console message, but in others there is no other information.

Comment: Firefox addon NoScript can cancel XHR request to untrusted hosts.

Comment: +​1, this is all accurate and "some sort of error occurred" is the practical interpretation. For people interested in a comprehensive list of possible causes given by the spec, I have posted a breakdown at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26451773/1709587.

Comment: Among the cases detailed by Mark Amery that cause me most trouble is the cors case. If the error causes the response to fails cors validation by the way, you will get a 0 status instead of the http status, since when cors validation fails, the response is not accessible. Especially frustrating when attempting to detect a web api undergoing maintenance and responding 503. If this api does not honor cors while under maintenance, you will not be able to detect the 503, you will just get 0, which can be caused by so many other things.

Comment: CORS issue I was faced: consider using `http` instead of `https` if your page was initially loaded through `http` and vice versa. Another words do not perform ajax `POST` via `https` if your page was accessed via `http` and do not perform ajax `POST` via `http` if your page was initiallly accessed via `https`.

Comment: Synchronous requests throw a more meaningfull exception on 0 status : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49573256/1192811

Comment: Yep, it was the CORS issue for me. Noticed afterwards that there was also a warning message thrown in Firefox console: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [url]. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: Cost me half a day to find out that the Firefox addon "uBlock origin" prevents AJAX calls if the URL contains the word `banner`... Wow!

Comment: This CORS issue comes up when Basic Authentication causes 401 on preflight OPTIONS request, fyi

Comment: Another cause of status 0 that you might want to investigate is expired certificate on server.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  One thing that I want to point out is that you can add custom properties to the XHR object.  Set some flags to false, then use the event handlers for onerror, onabort, and ontimeout to set the appropriate flag to true.  In my onreadystatechange handler, I set a custom property to the current state.  So if an error does happen, I have an idea as to what went wrong and what state the link was in.

Answer (score 36):

For what it is worth, depending on the browser, jQuery-based AJAX calls will call your success callback with a HTTP status code of 0.  We've found a status code of "0" usually means the user navigated to a different page before the AJAX call completed.

Not the same technology stack as you are using, but hopefully useful to somebody.

Comment: Yes, people probably get that issue a lot, since this page has  had 10,000 views.

Comment: Or should I say 25,000 views?

Comment: It is worth a lot: it is exactly what was misfiring in my automated tests. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Upvoted not because this is "the" right answer, but it is what was happening in my case.

Comment: This definitely does occur but it is not the *only* reason you will see error code == 0. you cannot assume its just the user navigating away and therefore filter out error messages of this type.

Answer (score 16):

`wininet.dll` returns both standard and non-standard status codes that are listed below.

```
401 - Unauthorized file
403 - Forbidden file
404 - File Not Found
500 - some inclusion or functions may missed
200 - Completed

12002 - Server timeout
12029,12030, 12031 - dropped connections (either web server or DB server)
12152 - Connection closed by server.
13030 - StatusText properties are unavailable, and a query attempt throws an exception
```

For the status code "zero" are you trying to do a request on a local webpage running on a webserver or without a webserver?

*[XMLHttpRequest status = 0 and XMLHttpRequest statusText = unknown](http://www.pearweb.com/javascript/XMLHttpRequest.html)* can help you if you are not running your script on a webserver.

Comment: Thanks for the codes. No, it is not a local request, it is a request to a web server on the internet, from a locally running vbscript.

Answer (score 11):

An HTTP response code of 0 indicates that the AJAX request was cancelled.

This can happen either from a timeout, XHR abortion or a firewall stomping on the request. A timeout is common, it means the request failed to execute within a specified time. An XHR Abortion is very simple to do... you can actually call .abort() on an XMLHttpRequest object to cancel the AJAX call. (*This is good practice for a single page application if you don't want AJAX calls returning and attempting to reference objects that have been destroyed.*) As mentioned in the marked answer, a firewall would also be capable of cancelling the request and trigger this 0 response.

XHR Abort: [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

It's worth noting that running the .abort() method on an XHR object will also fire the error callback. If you're doing any kind of error handling that parses these objects, you'll quickly notice that an aborted XHR and a timeout XHR are identical, but with jQuery the textStatus that is passed to the error callback will be "abort" when aborted and "timeout" with a timeout occurs. If you're using Zepto (very very similar to jQuery) the errorType will be "error" when aborted and "timeout" when a timeout occurs.

```
jQuery: error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
Zepto:  error(xhr, errorType, error);
```

Answer (score 6):

**Workaround: what we ended up doing**

We figured it was to do with firewall issues, and so we came up with a workaround that did the trick. If anyone has this same issue, here's what we did:

1. We still write the data to a text file on the local hard disk as we previously did, using an HTA.
2. When the user clicks "send data back to server", the HTA reads in the data and writes out an HTML page that includes that data as an XML data island (actually using a SCRIPT LANGUAGE=XML script block).
3. The HTA launches a link to the HTML page in the browser.
4. The HTML page now contains the javascript that posts the data to the server (using Microsoft.XMLHTTP).

Hope this helps anyone with a similar requirement. In this case it was a Flash game used on a laptop at tradeshows. We never had access to the laptop and could only email it to the client as this tradeshow was happening in another country.

Comment: Hi I am investigating a similar issue that is occurring to a customer in production. You say the problem for you was caused by a firewall. Do you happen to remember what was the effect caused by the firewall, or what was the firewall doing to cause this ?

Answer (score 5):

As detailed [by this answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507670/26510), a status code of 0 means the request failed for some reason, and a javascript library interpreted the fail as a status code of 0.

#### To test this you can do either of the following:

1) Use this chrome extension, [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) to redirect your url from the `https` version of your url to the `http` version, as this will cause a mixed content security error, and ultimately generate a status code of 0. The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to change your app at all, and you can simply "rewrite" your url using this extension.

2) Change the code of your app to optionally make your endpoint redirect to the `http` version of your url instead of the `https` version (or vice versa). If you do this, the request will fail with status code 0.

Comment: "Use this chrome extension" — A chrome extension? In an HTA application?

Comment: Good point for sure! But most people arriving here aren't getting here for HTA applications. They're googling "javascript http status code 0" or something like that, and arriving here - so I think the HTA part of this question is of the least importance, overall, and ultimately this is still relevant.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the status became 0 when i would forget to put the WWW in front of my domain. Because all my ajax requests were hardcoded http:/WWW.mydomain.com and the webpage loaded would just be http://mydomain.com it became a security issue because its a different domain. I ended up doing a redirect in my .htaccess file to always put www in front.

Answer (score 2):

I found a new and undocumented reason for status == 0. Here is what I had:

```
XMLHttpRequest.status === 0
XMLHttpRequest.readyState === 0
XMLHttpRequest.responseText === ''
XMLHttpRequest.state() === 'rejected'
```

It was not cross-origin, network, or due to cancelled requests (by code or by user navigation). Nothing in the developer console or network log.

I could find very little documentation on state() (Mozilla does not list it, W3C does) and none of it mentioned "rejected".

Turns out it was my **ad blocker** (uBlock Origin on Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because the AJAX call was being blocked by the browser because of the **same-origin policy**. It was the least expected thing, because all my HTMLs and scripts where being served from `127.0.0.1`. How could they be considered as having different origins?

Anyway, the root cause was an innocent-looking `<base>` tag:

```
<base href='<%=request.getScheme()%>://<%=request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath()%>/'/>
```

I removed the `<base>` tag, which I did not need by the way, and now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Lee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507670/1192811), you may find more information about the real cause by switching to [synchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) requests, as you'll get also an exception :

```
function request(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try {
        request.open('GET', url, false);
        request.send(null);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(url + ': ' + e);
    }
}
```

For example :

> NetworkError: A network error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this problem, this was giving me issues due to the AJAX request and a normal form request being sent. I solved it with the following line:

```
<form onsubmit="submitfunc(); return false;">
```

The key there is the return false, which causes the form not to send. You could also just return false from inside of submitfunc(), but I find explicitly writing it to be clearer.

Comment: Prevent Default works for this as well. It's a javascript function that prevents the browser from executing default behavior during events, allowing your to neatly override/prevent native functionality... return false does the same thing too.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that an ajax file upload exceeding the `client_max_body_size` directive for nginx will return this error code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on local PC, it won't work. To test Ajax example you need to place the HTML files on a web server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error occurred in a page requested with HTTP protocol, with a Javascript inside it trying to make an HTTPS request. And vice-versa.

After page loading, press F12 (or Ctrl + U) and take a look at the HTML code of your page. If you see something like that in your code:

```
<!-- javascript request inside the page -->
<script>
var ajaxurl = "https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
(...)
</script>
```

And your page was requested this way:

> http://example.com/example-page/2019/09/13/my-post/#elf_l1_Lw

You certainly will face this error.

To fix it, set the protocol of the Javascript request equal to the protocol of page request.

This situation involving different protocols, for page and js requests, was mentioned before in the answer of **Brad Parks** but, I guess the diagnostic technique presented here is easier, for the majority of users.