# .asp page calls a remote .php page

Tags: php, asp-classic, web-scraping

I need to send data from an IIS web server A to an Apache web server B. Two servers runs on different physical boxes and have different static IP addresses.
There is a processForm.asp running on server A, it processes some data, I wants to send the data to web server B, say let processData.php (on server B) to furthure process the data.
Is this possible? if yes, please help.

Thanks a lot for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send data from an .asp page on IIS to processData.php on Apache. I made a form on .asp, and used a hidden input control, the value of the input control is the data to be sent.
This is not what I was hoping for. I was hoping for an automatic solution like Gaby was suggestion. But Gaby's suggestion returns Error with status code 0.
If someone knows a workaround please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, this is perfectly possible. What you actually have to do depends on what your `processData.php` looks like and what it expects. [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) is your friend here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Microsoft.XMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505%28VS.85%29.aspx) or the [msxml.serverXMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766431%28VS.85%29.aspx) object..

example

```
Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

objXMLHTTP.Open "GET",aURL , False
objXMLHTTP.Send

Response.Write( objXMLHTTP.responseText )
```

Comment: Hi Gaby: Thanks very much for your reply. I am trying out your suggestion. From my question, processData.php on server B processes a php form(similar to welcome.php on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). How can I post the data in processForm.asp to processData.php?

Comment: Hi: I believe it should work in some cases. However I got "Error: returned status code 0". There is a separate thread about this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/http-status-code-0-what-does-this-mean-in-ms-xmlhttp