# how to proceed form only with a javascript without php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, web

i have a simple form like this:

```
 <form method="POST" action="do_something.php">
            <label for="name">Your name: </label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

and then a php file that do this:

```
<?php
    echo "your name is ". $_POST['name'];
?>
```

And my quest is to enabled default form sending and to write my own form sending method in javascript. But I'm not a big friend of javascript and i absolutely dont know where to start. :( Can anyone give me direction or help me? Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend starting with some research; you need to demonstrate that you've already put some work into trying to figure it out for yourself if you want any real help from anyone.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for Ajax Requests http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Client Side:

```
// This is the client-side script

// Initialize the Ajax request
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'send-ajax-data.php');

// Track the state changes of the request
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    // Ready state 4 means the request is done
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        // 200 is a successful return
        if(xhr.status === 200){
            alert(xhr.responseText); // 'This is the returned text.'
        }else{
            alert('Error: '+xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request
        }
    }
}

// Send the request to send-ajax-data.php
xhr.send(null);
```

Server Side:

```
<?php
// This is the server-side script

// Set the content type
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// Send the data back
echo "This is the returned text.";
?>
```

Comment: `-1` The OP requested no javascript.

Comment: @qwertynl No, OP said """not a big friend of javascript and i absolutely dont know where to start"""

Comment: OP is wrong. Pointing him to the right direction is probably the best way to go.

Comment: ok, i can't answer so here is screenshot with my answer: http://d.pr/i/8fJj

Comment: @user2202284 Well, I am not exactly sure what caused that error, but it most likely has something to do with the fact that you are not sending name as a variable with the Ajax Request.  For instance, look at the top of the page we are on now stackoverflow.com/quest/numb/post/numb?noredirect=1  in this case noredirect is the variable and 1 is its value.  You need to send your php the variable name along with a value.

Comment: yep, error:0 means XMLHttpRequest status 0 (responseText is empty) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005960/xmlhttprequest-status-0-responsetext-is-empty

Comment: ok, then I understand where the problem is. But how can i set the GET value? Or just to put some variable in html..

Comment: @user2202284 `xhr.open('get', 'send-ajax-data.php?and+your+variables+go+here');`

Answer (score 0):

The only client side code that exists is javascript.

That is the only thing you can use to play around with form submitting.

You can use any server side language you want, it does not have to be PHP.

Comment: Not true; there's also coffeescript

Comment: Which **translates** to javascript @DiMono . The browser only reads javascript at the moment (in February 2014).

Comment: Yes, my fault sorry. I meant Submitting form with javascript and send it to the php file i have with javascript. Without the default method.

Comment: For server side I suggest coldfusion. (Yes, this is a joke)

Comment: That's not technically true. There is already at least one browser natively reading Dart right now.

Comment: @qwertynl And c++ translates to assembly. It's still a distinct language.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine yeah, but only a dev version of that browser; also, old versions of IE support VBScript.