# HTTPXmlRequest return empty responsetext with status 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am encountering a similar situation to [XMLHttpRequest status 0 (responseText is empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005960/xmlhttprequest-status-0-responsetext-is-empty), but I felt that the difference was strong enough that it deserved it's own question.

So, my HTTPXmlRequest looks like this:

```
function displayIndicator() {
  alert(loader.responseText);
}

var loader = new XMLHttpRequest();
loader.onload = displayIndicator(); 
loader.open("get", "/products", true);
loader.send();
```

and `/products` when loaded in a browser window, or via

```
curl http://localhost:3000/cart/indicator;
```

returns a full fledged html document, (Im using it as a test page for the moment, eventually the end point will change but the correct endpoint behaves the same way).

this page is being served by a node server, so it's using a router and `/products` should resolve correctly wherever the script is being called from which makes me suspect that it's not the usual cross-domain issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an HTTP Status code of 0 have any meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing the `displayIndicator` function and assigning its return value (`undefined`) to `loader.onload`, you just need to remove the parenthesis:

```
loader.onload = displayIndicator;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I get for blindly copying sample code.