# Error reason for "XHR returned response code 0"

Tags: cors, fine-uploader

I'm trying to use fineuploader to upload an image to a complete url (http://website.net/folder1/folder2/). However i'm receiving this error:

```
error on file number x - <file name>. Reason: XHR returned response code 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are attempting to make a cross origin request without the server returning proper CORS headers (or in a browser that doesn't support CORS) or the response is coming back completely empty due to a network error, or some browser extension may be messing with the request.  You haven't provided any information about your situation at all, so this is the only answer i can offer.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Ray. What information can I provide that would give you a better insight?

Comment: Just tagging on to this. I have a site with about 400 users, and I get this error once in about 150 uploads. I'm using the S3 version of the uploader, so I'm not sure what's going on with it. CORS is set and works so the only thing I can think is that it's a rando issue with the users' browser... I'm thinking to add an error hook for this and suggest to users to try disabling extensions, or using another browser.

Comment: Another possibility is [a request time out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38097577/107625). Would be great if FineUploader [also would put](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/fb09dc444ac7bd14f30e3f929819e62eba9db8d6/client/js/uploader.basic.api.js#L1380) the `readyState` property of XHR into the error message.