# JSON Post to API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am trying to make a JSON Post to the Simpleconsign API, and I keep receiving a 0 error from the browser. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

JSONTest = function() {
    var resultDiv = $("#resultDivContainer");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
         key: "apikey,
        url: 'https://user.traxia.com/app/api/inventory', 
        contentType: "application/json",
         success: function(result){
            switch (result) {
                case true:
                    processResponse(result);
                    break;
                default:
                    resultDiv.html(result);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
};

</script>
```

I am a beginner at posting to the REST API's, so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your error message?

Comment: Yes! My error message pops up as 0 on the first dialog, and then blank on the second.

Comment: Have you tried [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/http-status-code-0-what-does-this-mean-in-ms-xmlhttp) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005960/xmlhttprequest-status-0-responsetext-is-empty)

Comment: Yes - neither seemed to really help with my issue. I've been at it for a couple hours now.

Comment: I don't see any data in your Ajax POST?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any data in your Ajax POST? This code should have work

```js
var postData = {
  "key": "Your API Key Here",
  "query": "some query",
  "consignorId": "123456",
  "includeItemsWithQuantityZero": "false"
};

JSONTest = function() {
  var resultDiv = $("#resultDivContainer");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: postData,
    url: 'https://user.traxia.com/app/api/inventory',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(result) {
      switch (result) {
        case true:
          processResponse(result);
          break;
        default:
          resultDiv.html(result);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
    }
  });
};
```

http://wiki.traxia.com/display/guide/List+and+Search+Inventory