# {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load

Tags: javascript, json

Error message is

> {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"NetworkError: Failed to
>   execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load...

When the following is executed

```
$.ajax({
      url: "http://swingd.achievedigital.com/action/user_signin.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      method: 'POST',
      async: false,
      data: pstr,
      success: function(data)
```

Changing

Async: false to true

causes this error:

> {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}--"error"--""

Anyone have any suggestions?  Anything would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it cross-domain? Have you checked whether that URL accessible?

Comment: Do you have a `beforeSend` defined somewhere?

Comment: There could be many reasons why you are seeing this - all this tells us is that your ajax request failed. Please log the errors and add those to this post. Do so by adding `error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, error ) {console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, error);}` below the `success` property and running the ajax request again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an HTTP Status code of 0 have any meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a response of 0 means that the request was not even allowed to reach the server (or the server did not support CORS).

- Cross domain problems (does http://swingd.achievedigital.com/action/user_signin.php have CORS enabled?)
- If the request is cancelled by the client (say if the page navigates away, or you call abort on the XHR)

See [XMLHttpRequest status 0 (responseText is empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005960/xmlhttprequest-status-0-responsetext-is-empty)