# How to get JSON data and store into variable.

Tags: javascript, html

I have a one variable file like this.

```
var geography = [
                    { id:"Country",   header:"",    width:150},
                    { id:"Capital",    header:"Capital", width:150},
                    { id:"Falg",   header:"Falg", width:150},
                    { id:"Language",   header:"Language", width:150},
                    {id:"Population", header:"Population", width:150},
                ],
```

Now I wanted to load this data from the json. I placed this data into JSON file and Using this code.

```
getGeography function(){
        var geography;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.json",true);
    }
```

Now from here how to store into a variable and return that.

Comment: Use [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) i.e. `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
    geography = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
};`

Answer (score 3):

It should be read when the ready state of xmlhttp is 4 and response status is 200. You should parse the response with JSON.parse(). However you can't return the value from the function. Because XMLHTTPRequest is asynchronous by default.

```
function getGeography() {
 var geography;
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.json",true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { 
  if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) { 
   geography = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText;) 
  }
 }
}
```

Instead of returning geography you have to programmatically read the value of geography when the AJAX request is complete. Something like this ([read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/2168552)):

Instead of writing code like this:

```
function anotherFunc() {
 var geography = getGeography();
 thenDoSomething(geography);
}
```

Write like this:

```
function anotherFunc() {
 getGeography();
}
function getGeography() {
 var geography;
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.json",true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { 
  if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) { 
   geography = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
   thenDoSomething(geography); 
  }
 }
}
```

It's like handing over the control of execution of rest of the code to getGeography() function, instead of expecting a return value from the function and then using that value. The getGeography() function resumes execution of rest of the code with the value received from AJAX response, when the AJAX call completes.

Comment: DO I need to declare `geography` as an array ?

Comment: No, javascript does not require types defined. with `var geography;` you declare variable and assign `undefined` value. You can assign whatever you want and then assign whatever else. The type will be changed automatically.

Comment: In this case also I am gettong  
status is getting 0 instead of 200

Comment: @David it could be due to several reasons. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10173639/2168552) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26451773/2168552)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of jQuery but in this case, you would probably benefit from this.

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  // data is your result
  console.log(data);
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use XMLHttRequest() :

```
<script>
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var geography = [];
    req.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
        // XMLHttpRequest.DONE === 4
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                geography = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log(geography);
                alert("Great Success : check console !");
            } else {
                alert("Something has gone really Bad !");
            }
        }
    };

    req.open('GET', 'data.json', true);
    req.send(null);
```

Be careful to use correct JSON :

```
[
    {"id":"Country","header":"","width":150},
    { "id":"Capital","header":"Capital", "width":150},
    { "id":"Falg","header":"Falg","width":150},
    { "id":"Language","header":"Language", "width":150},
    { "id":"Population", "header":"Population", "width":150}
]
```

Comment: status is getting 0 instead of 200

Comment: Do you use a web server ? You should not open your html file locally I mean via the file protocol. Use a web server. You can use "Web server for chrome" for instance, which is a chrome addon. I tested my example with it and it works fine :-)