# RxJS 5: how to get statusCode on catch

Tags: ajax, rxjs, redux-observable

How do I get the status code back from a failed `ajax` call in RxJS so I can decide what to do with it?

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax'

ajax('https://my.url')
  .map(xhr => console.log('woo', xhr.response))
  .catch(err => console.log('status code??'))
```

there are some fields on the `err` response and one of them is `status` but it's always `0` irrespective of the statusCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit:

I missed the fact that you see `error.status` so the question is just that why it's zero.

It's a browser thing. [It's zero by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status), and only gets changed when the request actually comes back. If it does not for any reason complete, it remains zero. That includes aborted requests, CORS issues, being offline, DNS issues, and any other network error. Which makes sense, cause there are no HTTP codes for most of these cases. A CORS request error might itself have a 401 (or other code) but the browser does not expose it to you programmatically.

Unfortunately, when this happens there's not much you can do programmatically to know what caused it. You can check `navigator.onLine` and if it's false might infer that it was caused by not being connected to the internet, though that's not 100% reliable.

In other cases, you're screwed, programmatically. There's no error message property with an explanation or other way to know. The true reason the error is typically in the dev console (so check there), but not accessible programmatically for security reasons.

Here are some additional resources about this:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26451773/1770633
- [XMLHttpRequest status 0 (responseText is empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005960/xmlhttprequest-status-0-responsetext-is-empty)

---

In v5 (and at least in v4 too), status is available as a top-level property `status` of the provided error object:

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax'

ajax('https://my.url')
  .map(xhr => console.log('woo', xhr.response))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('status code', error.status);
    // also available as error.xhr.status (inside the raw XMLHttpRequest object)
    return Observable.empty(); // switch to an empty stream i.e. swallow error
  });
```

Note that `catch` is used to catch an error **and then switch to a different Observable that you must return**. So the error must be handled. If you do not want to handle the error, but just want to log it, you can use `do`:

```
ajax('https://my.url')
  .map(xhr => console.log('woo', xhr.response))
  .do({ error: err => console.log('status code', err.status) })
```

Comment: You said on twitter: "I'd already mentioned the status field in my question, it's always '0', I want the response statusCode eg 401"

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. Edited my answer.

Comment: awesome, that makes sense now .. even if it is a little irritating.

Answer (score -1):

As per documentation: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/ajax.md

You do it like below:

```
ajax('https://my.url')
  .map(xhr => console.log('woo', xhr.response))
  .catch((err, status) => console.log(status))
```

Comment: That link is to rxjs v4, not v5, but in both v4 and v5 it's the same `status` property on the error object itself, not the second argument. In v4 the second argument is nothing (undefined) but in v5 it's the source observable the catch was applied to.