# XMLHttpRequest response null

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, express

Hi I'm new to web development. I have three files, index.html, myscript.js and server.js. A button on index.html calls the messageServer function in myscript.js which sends an XMLHttpRequest to server.js running Express on Node. The server receives the request but the response in myscript.js is always null. The readyState goes 1 and then 4. Why is it null? Thanks in advance
Edit: the response status code is 0
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title id="title">Page Title</title>
        <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="header">Header</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Message Server" onclick="messageServer();">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

myscript.js

```
function messageServer() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'http://localhost:8888/';

    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {

        log("Ready state: " + xhr.readyState + ", response: " + xhr.response);

        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            return xhr.response;
        }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

and server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = 8888;

let requestCount = 1;

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Received get request ' + requestCount);
    ++requestCount;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({myKey: 'myValue'}));
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: you set  response type as json, why are you then sending it in stringified form? change it to `res.send({myKey: 'myValue'});`

Comment: @kiddorails I got this error: "TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer" when I did that

Comment: change it back to older version and add `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` before it.

Comment: or `res.json({myKey; 'myValue'})` should work too ideally

Comment: Tried both. Still null

Comment: ok. instead of checking for xhr.response, try `xhr.responseText`

Comment: and remove `xhr.responseType = 'json';` if it still doesn't work and give it a shot again

Comment: and if still doesn't work, move `xhr.responseType = 'json';` after `xhr.open` and try again with both `xhr.response` and `xhr.responseText`

Comment: Okay so moving the responseType to after open: with responseText both are empty strings and with response, when readyState is 1, it's an empty string and when readyState is 4, it's null.

Comment: I tried the other things too, didn't work

Comment: Are you even getting 200 response there? Can you just confirm it with `console.log(xhr.status)` ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AnkurGel/9af39c377bf3ce1f167f9abf4ebb7568 This example works perfectly fine for me

Comment: The status code was 0. Maybe it's because I'm running the server and the client-side script on the same computer?

Comment: status code, not readyState

Comment: I tried that API endpoint in your example and it worked so. Wait it got a 400 so it didn't work but something different happened

Comment: yup status code of 0

Comment: change log to console.log in myscript.js, also check any error message on console .

Comment: Bit of a stupid question, but how? When I press the button in the browser it's not linked to the console right so nothing shows up. Even if there's a way to execute it independently, the server is blocking the console from me running any commands

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest status 0 (responseText is empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005960/xmlhttprequest-status-0-responsetext-is-empty)

Comment: For other reasons see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning/26451773#26451773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main problem is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (cross origin resource sharing) is not enabled on express, chrome is bit strict about CORS.

put below code before app.get to enable [cross-origin resource sharing](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

complete server.js should be as below

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

const port = 8888;
let requestCount = 1;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Received get request ' + requestCount);
    ++requestCount;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({myKey: 'myValue'}));
});

app.listen(port);
```

Then check on network tab of developer tool, you should see `{"myKey":"myValue"}` in response.

Comment: Yes! That's it, thank you. Just a quick question: is this normal to have to add this to node apps? Is it because I'm running it locally or what

Comment: it is not just applicable to node apps, in your example it is  because of XmlHttpRequest, here is full link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS , and What requests use CORS? section should explain it. even in my answer I put "*" it should be your domain/* so for your example http://localhost:8888/* .