# Downloading file using ajax not working on firefox

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to download a generated file(pdf) using Ajax, it's working perfectly in Chrome and IE but not in FireFox.
Here is my code :

```
function Download(urlAction, urlDownload) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: urlAction,
        data: {
            'itemIds': checkedItems,
            'dateMin': datemin.toISOString(),
            'dateMax': datemax.toISOString()
        },
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('fff', data);
            if (data.success) {
                window.location = urlDownload;
            }
        }
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
            console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
            console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
            console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
            console.log("error: " + err);
        }
    });
}
}
```

In the UrlAction I generate the file in Json format and post it in a session, then calling it again in my urlDownload.
In Chrome and IE the file is downloaded without reloading the page, but in Firefox, it only reload the page.

The error says:

- readyState: 0
- responseText: undefined
- status: 0
- text status: error
- error: undefined

Comment: Create a function for the failure condition, not just the success condition. See what the error is. I'm going to guess it is a TLS issue, in my experience Firefox is much less forgiving of certificate problems than other browsers.

Comment: @Crowcoder It writes 'undefined'

Comment: Look at `error`, not `xhr`.

Comment: @Crowcoder See edit, nothing new

Comment: Double click the `error` in console, it will navigate you to the error line, add a debugger/break point over there , refresh page, then you will find what is error details, including call stacks. post them here or resolve it by yourself.

Comment: @Dongdong there is no error in console to be clicked, break point doesn't help if no error is readable.

Comment: remove parameter: `datatype: "json",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that worked for me is that I put the button (the one that calls this method) out of the form div, and it stoped reloading the page ,the download worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) says:

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String The type of data that you're **expecting back from the
>   server**. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response

so you can try to remove the parameter first.

About your error status, it's `0`, you could find detailed reason here:
[XMLHttpRequest status 0 (responseText is empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005960/xmlhttprequest-status-0-responsetext-is-empty)

About your error handler,`error: function (xhr, textStatus, err)`:

1. `xhr.status` shows reason, you have to check your server side configuration; but you did not mentions what is server environment.
2. `textStatus` could be following values:`"timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror"`;
3. `err` could be undefined if request did not reach to your server side location;

Here is official document:

> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown ) A
>   function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
>   "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array
>   of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler
>   is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.
>   This is an Ajax Event.