# TypeError : NetworkError when attemptimg to fetch a resource

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, firefox-addon, fetch-api

I'm trying to have my Firefox extension send/recieve data to/from a spring boot app running on `localhost:8080/` and I am getting this error.

Here is the request -

```
    var req = new Request("localhost:8080/all", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' },
    });
```

Here is the controller function for `localhost:8080/all` -

```
    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Product> getAllProducts()
    {
        return productrepository.findAll();
    }
```

I've also added `@CrossOrigin(origins="*")` to the controller class

I've added `"*://localhost/"` to `permissions` in the manifest of the extension.

I know the server works fine and that its not a CORS issue because I tried it with `curl`

```
curl -H "Origin:https://google.com/" -H "Accept:application/json" -H "method:GET" localhost:8080/all --verbose
```

And it returned these response headers along with the output json

```
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem

I decided  to try the same GET request but with XHR and got a status 0 and an empty responsetext . On searching for what could be the reason I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005960/xmlhttprequest-status-0-responsetext-is-empty) so I replaced `localhost:8080/all` with `http://localhost:8080/all` in my fetch API request and it worked . It was a permissions issue then I guess.