# XMLHttpRequest not returning any data

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code on my web site:

```
    var fileUrl = constants.homeTextUrl;

    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();

    rawFile.open("GET", fileUrl, true);

    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0) {
                var text = rawFile.responseText;
                process(text); // text is null here unless local file
            }
        }
    };

    rawFile.send(null);
```

When **constants.homeTextUrl** points to a local file on the same web server, all is well.
But when it is "http://members.ozemail.com.au/~rliq/home.txt" (a valid url you can check it), then nothing is returned.

Does anyone know what the issue may be?

Comment: It may be a CORS issue, are you receiving a 200 status?

Comment: Maybe this post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005960/xmlhttprequest-status-0-responsetext-is-empty

Comment: Most likely Same Origin Policy (CORS) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: I get 200 for the local file, but 0 for the remote one.

Comment: yeah CORS it is.