# Express and ajax posting using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

Express doesn't seem to be responding to my ajax request. The post request status appears to be pending for a long time when I look at it in the network tab of the chrome inspector and then fails. This is my express code:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({secret: 'fasfasasasfasfa'}));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.post('/test.html', function (req,res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send({ some: JSON.stringify({response:'json' })});
  res.end();
})
```

And here's my jQuery code:

```
working = function() {
    console.log("works")
}

$.ajax({
    url:"test.html",
    data: {'name':'hello'},
    type: "POST",
    success: working
  })
```

The success function never gets called, and the console log of req.body doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When the request finally fails, what HTTP status code do you get? Is there any error message in the console when it fails?

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to this

Comment: No worries about being new. You've already mentioned the network tab. You should be able to look at the request in there to determine HTTP status code when it finishes. The console is the same place that your console.log statements print to when you run your code. Uncaught exceptions usually get printed to there.

Comment: No code seems to show up when it fails, although I implemented an error handler in my ajax request and that sends a http code of 0

Comment: Your initialization is wrong - you have put static file server route before the post rest receiver. Your /test.html will first try static file and fail before reaching rest receiver. You need to move express.static after app.post

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in the comments, you're getting a status code of 0 back.

[Does an HTTP Status code of 0 have any meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning)

Check to make sure you're server is reachable from where you're testing and that the URL your making the request to is actually pointing at the server you want to send the request to.

In other words you probably need to fix this line

```
url:"test.html",
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because even if I change it to the full IP address, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `.html` extension on a route in Express as this makes it think its looking for a static resource. Use "pretty URLs" instead.

```
// Express code...
app.post('test', function(req, res, next){
  // Do stuff to process POST request
});

// AJAX code...
$.ajax({
  url: 'test',
  ...
});
```

Hope that helps!