# What does sc-status 0 mean?

Tags: iis, iis-8, iis-logs

I am reviewing an issue in our servers by gathering statistics on our IIS Logs.  I have noticed several entries for a given path that have an sc-status of 0.  I have tried to find what that could mean, but every blob/documentation site I view lists out the http status codes and what they mean.

What does sc-status 0 mean? All of these entries have a sc-substatus of 0 and sc-win32-status of 64.

Comment: We are seeing this as well. Did you ever figure out what was causing it?

Answer (score 2):

It means that the client dropped the connection

Answer (score 0):

sc-status (Protocol Status)

Have a read of these, hopefully you'll find the answer in one of them.

[Does an HTTP Status code of 0 have any meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning)

[What does HTTP status code 0 mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858251/what-does-http-status-code-0-mean)

[Does an HTTP Status code of 0 have any meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning)

Answer (score 0):

i'm also facing the same issue, 2% of web calls returns:

- sc-status: 0
- sc-substatus: 7
- sc-win32-status: 64

I can't understand from the documentation what is occurring.

Comment: Activating the request failed tracing i matched that all the rows logged as 0 on the basic logs were 403.7 on the detailed one, for mutual SSL with a client with a bad certificate calling the server.
Fixed that, no more 0 status codes.