# Karma test exception in angular2 application

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Can I get a  better log or something? I don't have a clue where to look for the error.

```
Chrome 57.0.2987 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Response with status: 0  for URL: null
  at webpack:///~/rxjs/Subscriber.js:238:0 <- src/test.ts:737
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 31 of 31 ERROR (1.258 secs / 1.352 secs)
```

Comment: When I add a new *.spec.ts file in the project it crashes

Comment: Any progress on that? i have the same issue and unfortunately cannot reproduce it locally as it only happens on the automated build pipeline. As it is extremely difficult to debug i would appreciate anything that might help me.

Comment: @Entrodus sorry, no progress. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is making an HTTP request and failing. Per the error message, the URL is `null` and the status code is `0`. `0` isn't an actual HTTP status code, but it can mean a timeout occurred. This [Stack Overflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858251/what-does-http-status-code-0-mean) has some pointers on what `0` can mean.

I ran into this when testing a component. Mocking the HTTP request solved the problem. For how to do that, I recommend this thoughtram article on [testing HTTP services](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/11/28/testing-services-with-http-in-angular-2.html).