# .NET CORE API not working with Angular on Ubuntu server

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core, ubuntu-22.04

I keep getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when things get sent to my API from the frontend on my ec2 instance.

I'm running an ubuntu server using AWS and I'm using nginx to proxy anything from port 80 to the angular part of the application. Everything works as it should locally when running the angular on localhost:4200 and the API on https://localhost:7040. On the server, I can reach the angular frontend as expected using the public DNS, but cannot get past the login/register page as it requires the API.

For clarification: on the server the angular build is static and I am running the API using kestrel and specifying https://localhost:7040 using --urls to force it to change the default url. However, if it is awsdomain.com/api/something then it is redirected to https://localhost:7040/api/something where my API (.NET Core) is running via kestrel.

I can think of three issues so far that could be causing this.

1. for some reason when I use the `lsof -i :7040` command, nothing shows as listening, however when I use the  `ss -tuln | grep LISTEN | grep ':7040'` I can see my kestrel service listening properly. To my understanding I should be able to see it listening using the lsof command, so perhaps this means something is going wrong.
2. Maybe I am not proxying properly. To my understanding, what I have done in my proxy pass is reroute anything from my ec2 instance with /api in it to go to the https://localhost:7040 with the exact same path called (so aws.com/api == https://localhost:7040/api and aws.com/api/login == https://localhost:7040/api/login). Here is how I configured it in my nginx sites-available:

```
server {

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/app/AngularApp/dist/angularapp/browser/;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;



    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
     }

    location ~* /api(/.*)?$ {
        proxy_pass         https://localhost:7040/api$1;
    }



    location /phpmyadmin {
         root /usr/share/;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                root /usr/share/;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }

            location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                root /usr/share/;
            }
    }






}
```

3. The third issue that could be occurring may be related to the fact the ec2 is http and I am routing to https. I am new to server stuff so I don't quite understand everything but from what I have seen, it can work localhost because there's a local development certificate (SSL), but when I put everything on the instance I may need my own certificate I have to purchase to enable https?

I am the server person for a group and I cannot understand what is going wrong on the instance. Please let me know if any of these may be the problem or if there is anything I may not have thought of.

Comment: Try postman to see if your server is reachable. If it is check the errors from network tab. It might be CORS or self sign sertificate if you use it. About https NGINX can redirrect from http to https and vice verse so it shouldn't be the case with proper configuration, but chrome might block http requests, so just allow them for your url.

Comment: @Ricudo the network tab is the one throwing the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Sorry for the lack of clarification. The server is reachable but when use dev tools and any action routes to the API, that is the only error message I receive. That's why I am so confused as it is not very specific . I know we have CORS but I thought I solved it when I set it to builder.AllowAnyOrigins(). To my knowlege, there is no SSL certificate but I will have to ask my developer.  They told me that the API  builds the app with https middleware and I am not sure if that involves a SSL.

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED may be because of the different reasons. Provide more information about the error. Which code (400, 401, 503...) what the full error message. If it is about https you can try copy the full path of the rejected request and paste it in a different browser tab. Browser may say that it is unsafe and ask approvement to reach it, after such and approvement the problem might be solved.

Comment: The SSL Certificate of your webapi: is it a self signed certificate? If you want to disable certificate validation, you might have to either add some code or add the SSL certificate to your trusted root certificates. See this link for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526711/using-a-self-signed-certificate-with-nets-httpwebrequest-response

Comment: @Ricudo oddly enough it is 0.  
 ERROR 
Js {headers: t, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'https://localhost:7040/api/auth/test', ok: false, …}
error
: 
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
headers
: 
t {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message
: 
"Http failure response for https://localhost:7040/api/auth: 0 Unknown Error"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
0
statusText
: 
"Unknown Error"
url
: 
"https://localhost:7040/api/auth/test"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Ir

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper I am unsure of what that means. I thought SSL stood for self signed certificate in the first place? to my understanding our app works using something called https middleware

Comment: I've never met 0, but here is discusion about the topic, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858251/http-status-code-0-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain