# java: deploying web service on static IP and accessing from outside network

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat

I have designed a REST Web Service in java and I'm running it locally on Apache Tomcat server.

Now I want to access the web service from outside my network. I have a static IP address.

How do I access it from another network?

Comment: have you tried http(s)://<ip>/<service_path>??

Comment: yes but it loads infinitely without response

Comment: What softwares should i use

Comment: you can try using POSTMAN or SOAP-UI to hit the service.

Comment: I am getting response status 0

Comment: The server is not responding or is not reachable, it means. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning

Comment: you can try hitting it from the machine on which you deployed like https(s)://localhost:port/<svc_path>

Comment: also check if you are mentioning proper port

Comment: on local machine it is working and im using 8080 port

Comment: are you using same port while connecting from other machine? and u sure you have static IP? is that accessible through internet?

Comment: yes im using same port and have static ip but it is not accessible through internet

Answer (score 0):

after having chat with you, i can suggest following.

- check if your network/firewall have port 8080 open. if not make it
  open for communication.
- try doing telnet to that IP with the port 8080 to check if that port is open
  for connection to that machine, if not contact to your network
  operator.

it seems connection problem to me more than service related issue.