# catch jquery ajax error later

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to make an http request to a freebox ( I don't know if it's exist outside france )

The freebox don't access the CORS request, but she make what I will.

For example if I make a request for power :

```
http://hd1.freebox.fr/pub/remote_control?code=5818260&key=power&long=false&repeat=1
```

The freebox player start, and I have a CORS error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hd1.freebox.fr/pub/remote_control?code=5818260&key=power&long=false&repeat=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

It's okay, but I will check the http header for this request, for example if I will check if my code is good, the freebox return 403 for bad code.

I tried to get the statusCode with Jquery :

```
            xhr = $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: url,
            crossDomain: true,
            statusCode: {
                500: function () {
                    alert("Une erreur s'est produite !");
                },
                403: function(){
                    alert("aaaaa")
                    throw new badTelecommandeCode();
                },
                404: function(){
                    throw new freeboxNotFound();
                },
                0: function(){console.log(0)}
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

All this time, the status code is 0, and "error" don't launch. I have this error in console :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hd1.freebox.fr/pub/remote_control?code=5818260&key=power&long=false&repeat=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

You can see the end of this answer

> "The response had HTTP status code 403.".
>   Just before jquery write an error ( in red ):

```
GET http://hd1.freebox.fr/pub/remote_control?code=5818260&key=power&long=false&repeat=1
```

I try to catch the error :

```
        try{
        xhr = $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: url,
            crossDomain: true,
            statusCode: {
                500: function () {
                    alert("Une erreur s'est produite !");
                },
                403: function(){
                    alert("aaaaa")
                    throw new badTelecommandeCode();
                },
                404: function(){
                    throw new freeboxNotFound();
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
```

I have try to search, where the error has catch by jquery :

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js line 8634
```

Do You find a way for catch the CORS message, and parse it, or catch the jquery message, and why not get the statusCode or any information .

For the little troller, the way "Send a request to freebox developer for accept CORS" is already make, but no answer. I can't pass by a webserver .

My Current challenge is : "I'm a lambda user will see my TV, but my Free Tv Remote don't work, what I can make easily, with my smartphone/PC"

**UPDATE1** : 
I have make an example :

if it's work good :

```
    xhr = $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://hd1.freebox.fr/pub/remote_control?code=5818261&key=right&long=false&repeat=1",
    crossDomain: true,
    statusCode: {
        500: function () {
            alert("Une erreur s'est produite !");
        },
        403: function(){
            alert("badTelecommandeCode")
        },
        404: function(){
            alert("freeboxNotFound")
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        // console.log(err);
    },
    fail:function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Good key, good code, my TV make the action, and return a CORS error
[image: CORS Without http error]

I will catch, if the code is bad, or if the key doesn't exist :

```
        xhr = $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://hd1.freebox.fr/pub/remote_control?code=5818261&key=ping",
    crossDomain: true,
    statusCode: {
        500: function () {
            alert("Une erreur s'est produite !");
        },
        403: function(){
            alert("badTelecommandeCode")
        },
        404: function(){
            alert("freeboxNotFound")
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        // console.log(err);
    },
    fail:function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
xhr = $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://hd1.freebox.fr/pub/remote_control?code=222222&key=ping",
    crossDomain: true,
    statusCode: {
        500: function () {
            alert("Une erreur s'est produite !");
        },
        403: function(){
            alert("badTelecommandeCode")
        },
        404: function(){
            alert("freeboxNotFound")
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        // console.log(err);
    },
    fail:function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

[image: CORS error with http status error]
I have a CORS, no problem, but how I can catch the text, say the http status .

**For information :**
freebox.fr is a NAT rules, redirect to my router ( the freebox ), hdX.freebox.fr go to the API for TV player hd number X

Comment: You can use promises for this

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning/26451773#26451773
Error status `0` can happen when `the request was CORS, and the response couldn't be shared`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum any example ?

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett yes, but something write the http status in console, so he can read the response ... Can i catch this ?

Answer (score 0):

Still not certain interpret Question correctly. There does not appear to be a response returned from `url` . `0` does not appear to be a valid `HTTP` response code see [HTTP status code 0 - what does this mean for fetch, or XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/http-status-code-0-what-does-this-mean-in-ms-xmlhttp/) . The `error` logged to `console`

```
GET http://hd1.freebox.fr/pub/remote_control?code=5818260&key=power&long=false&repeat=1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

after request below

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("GET", "http://hd1.freebox.fr/pub/remote_control?code=5818260&key=power&long=false&repeat=1", true);
 xhr.onload = function() {
   console.log(this.status)
 }
 xhr.onerror = function(e) {
   console.log(e, this.status)
 }
 xhr.send();
```

Comment: I Have the same return if it's work or not :/, the status is "0"

Comment: @thib3113 What is requirement ? , expected result ?

Comment: 1 - check if the remote tv network code is good ( code=XXX in http ), this return http error 403 if not valid

but the server don't accept CORS

Comment: @thib3113 Tried opening new tab , typing _"http ://hd1.freebox.fr/pub/remote_control?code=5818260&key=power&long=false&repeat=1"_ into address bar, press enter, open `console` , see "network" tab ? There does not appear to be a response returned from `url` ?

Comment: yes, it's work for me ( but, it's not my problem ), i will make this programaticaly, so I have update my current challenge in topic .

Comment: Is requirement to `catch`  `statusCode` `0` , then do stuff ?

Comment: no, i will catch the real status code, the same Status code i have in the console by the error ( see in topic )

Comment: @thib3113 Not certain interpret requirement correctly ?

Comment: juste make a http call for get the http status of this, and make in function .

Comment: you have an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT because you don't have a freebox . hd1.freebox.fr is a specific routage rule create by the freebox . the number after "hd" is the number of your hd player

Comment: @thib3113 Ok. Not certain how can help ? The `fail:` is not an options property of `$.ajax(options)` , but a separate method ; see http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Comment: (i have see your comment before update), so, for the documentation, it's a big joke ... this API is never document ... she was make for a late version, and delete, and she come back, but without any informations ... a little informations in the web :/

I look with fail . I have try with parse an iframe, but she have a CORS too :/

**update :**
I have try with .fail(), but it's return the same information, status : 0, and text : "error"

Comment: @thib3113 Actually attempted to visit "freebox.fr" ; "You attempted to reach **freebox.fr**, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as ***.free.fr**"

Comment: yes and ? If I go on http://mafreebox.free.fr or her IP : http://212.27.38.253/ , I see : 
http://www.zupmage.eu/i/aUCU0vTk3L.jpg