# getting "uncaught exception: out of memory" in firebug doing an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've been trying to debug an ajax call with chrome and firefox. I'm newbie in both. When debbuging with chrome, I was getting an ajax response with the two last params `(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` empty and the first one was xhr status 0. I said sometimes, because I was getting some times an xhr status 200, and the params `textStatus, errorThrown` was printing parse error, and unexpected character '<'. I've been looking at my php code and this '<' is nowere because I've been doing a test: to comment every php code and to return the same `$_POST['json']` that php is getting from the ajax call, and I was getting the same errors. I've been looking at my json and is well formed. Confused by all these errors and confusing debug tools that I don't understand very well, I moved to firefox and firebug, and there I get another diferent message: "uncaught exception: out of memory"
I've been reading some others developers asking the same question, and tryed the accepted answers but I still can't find the issue, that's why I post my code here, hoping somebody can help. Thanks a lot!

html code:

```
                   <input type="submit" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out" value='Submit' onClick="setTypeAdvanced()" style= "
    position: relative;
    top: -152px;
    left: 129px;
" />
```

jscript code in index.js:

```
function setTypeAdvanced(){

    var advancedFormVars = {};
    /**SHOW*/

    if(document.getElementById('OfferID').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox1'] = document.getElementById('OfferID').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('offerName').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox2'] =document.getElementById('offerName').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('campaignID').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox3'] = document.getElementById('campaignID').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('campaignName').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox4'] = document.getElementById('campaignName').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('installs').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox5'] = document.getElementById('installs').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('revenue').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox6'] = document.getElementById('revenue').value;
    }


    /** FILTERS */
    if(document.getElementById('offerIDFilt').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox7'] =  document.getElementById('offerIDFilt').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('publisherIDFilt').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox8'] = document.getElementById('publisherIDFilt').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('publisherIDTextVal').value.length >'0'){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox9'] =  document.getElementById('publisherIDTextVal').value;
        publisherIDTextVal  =  document.getElementById('publisherIDTextVal').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('offIDTextVal').value.length > '0'){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox10'] =  document.getElementById('offIDTextVal').value;
    }

        /**GROUP BY*/
    if(document.getElementById('dates').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox11'] = document.getElementById('dates').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('geos').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox12'] = document.getElementById('geos').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('browsers').checked == true){//arreglar no coge checked, coge objeto html
        advancedFormVars['checkbox13']= document.getElementById('browsers').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('oS').checked == true){//arreglar coge undefined
        advancedFormVars['checkbox14'] = document.getElementById('oS').value;
    }





    /**ORDER BY*/
    if(document.getElementById('installsGroupBy').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox15']= document.getElementById('installsGroupBy').value;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('revenueGroupBy').checked == true){
        advancedFormVars['checkbox16']= document.getElementById('revenueGroupBy').value;
    }

    advancedFormVars['none']= (typeof none=== 'undefined') ? 'default' : none;
    advancedFormVars['ASC']= (typeof ASC === 'undefined') ? 'default' : ASC;
    advancedFormVars['DESC']= (typeof DESC === 'undefined') ? 'default' : DESC;




    loadFormAdvanced(advancedFormVars);



}
function loadFormAdvanced(advancedFormVars){

    var json = JSON.stringify(advancedFormVars);

    $.ajax({
        url : 'AL_loadForm.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            json:json
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert('error '+errorThrown);
              alert('status '+textStatus);
              alert('xhr status '+jqXHR.status);
            }
    });
}
```

edit to add my php code:

```
<?php 
    if($_POST){ 
         if($_POST['json']){
              echo json_encode($_POST['json']); //also tryed echo($_POST['json']);
              } 
         }
?>
```

And this is my json:

```
{"checkbox1":"OfferID","checkbox2":"Offer Name","checkbox3":"CampaignID","checkbox4":"CampaignName","checkbox5":"Installs","checkbox6":"Revenue","checkbox7":"OfferID","checkbox8":"PublisherID","checkbox9":"some publisher","checkbox10":"some offer","checkbox12":"Geos","checkbox15":"Installs","none":"default","ASC":"default","DESC":"default"}
```

it has been copy/pasted from console log right before beeing sended in the ajax call:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(advancedFormVars);
console.log(json);
$.ajax({
    url : 'AL_loadForm.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
        json:json
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data);
```

Comment: this is my php:<?php if($_POST){ if($_POST['json']){ echo json_encode($_POST['json']); } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setTypeAdvanced` without parameters upon clicking on your `submit` button. The function builds an object called `advancedFormVars` and calls `loadFormAdvanced(advancedFormVars)`. After you `stringify` the variable, you are passing it to an AJAX POST request to `AL_loadForm.php`. You receive `0` as status code, which can mean many different things (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning)). Basically, you need to check the logs of your server to know what happened. Did it receive the request? If so, was there an error? Also, you need to check the network tab of your browser console to see what response did you receive. That `<` is a big clue, it probably means that your server sends back some HTML, which might be too large, possibly due to a response dataset being too large or the server not handling posts well.

EDIT:

This PHP code is incorrect:

```
<?php 
    if($_POST){ 
         if($_POST['json']){
              echo json_encode($_POST['json']); //also tryed echo($_POST['json']);
              } 
         }
?>
```

I assume that you want to know whether the request is post and if so, then check whether it has a `'json'` element, but `$_POST` is truey, even if it is a get request, since then it is an empty `array` and `$_POST['json']` will lead to error if you do not have a 'json' element. Modify it like this:

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){ 
         if(isset($_POST['json'])){
              echo json_encode($_POST['json']); //also tryed echo($_POST['json']);
              } 
         }
?>
```

Note, that you are encoding it into JSON and then wanting to `alert` it. You should not `alert` large json strings. Use `console.log` instead.

Comment: But what I don't understand is that is happening with this php code: <?php 

 if($_POST){
    require 'AL_createTbObj.php';
    
    if($_POST['json']){
        echo json_encode($_POST['json']);
}
}

Comment: @user3033437, I have edited my answer to add further help.