# Phonegap - Can't access GeoJson Stored in Data Directory

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, openlayers-3, geojson

I'm working on trying to incorporate an updatable vector layer into my phonegap build with OpenLayers 3. It will check the server for updates and download a new file when necessary.

I can download the file and store it no problem (I use the same code in other apps for non-geojson file types with no problems). I've verified it's existence using the following:

```
var resortURL = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "resorts.geojson";
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(resortURL,function(e){
   console.log("located");
},function(e){
   console.log("missing");
});
```

When I go to access the file using OL:

```
var resortSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: resortURL,
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});
var resortBoundary = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: resortSource
});
map.addLayer(resortBoundary);
```

The above fails to add any data to the map, although it does add the layer. I have gone even further and added the geojson file directly to the assets www folder pre-build and accessed it using:

```
url: "json/resorts.geojson"
```

Requesting the file from the assets location works exactly as expected. The problem is when I try access it after downloading it to the Data Directory on Android and then trying to access through there. Am I missing something? I've been trying everything under the sun trying to make it work.

Comment: What does your web console say about the geojson file under the 'network' tab?? Does it show a request going out for the geojson file?? was it read?? What does `resortSource.getFeatures().length` show??

Comment: @GoinOff The length of the array is zero. The network tab shows the request going out with a file size of 0 B.  It looks identical to when it works other than the Status in the network tab shows 'finished' instead of the typical 200.  I've never seen that before.

Comment: I've had numerous browser caching issues using `url` property of `ol.source.Vector` where it uses an old version of the geojson file.  Have you tried clearing your cache in your web browser?? Are you sure the geojson file contains valid geojson?? http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html

Comment: @GoinOff I could, but I don't think that's where the issue lies. And beside I have information stored in the browser cache I wouldn't want deleted!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the vector loader function to handle fetching your geojson files. I've had numerous caching issues not using a vector loading function to fetch geojson files and the method below eliminated that problem. For example:

```
var utils = {
    refreshGeoJson: function(source,url) {
      var now = Date.now();
      if (typeof url == 'undefined') {
        url = source.getUrl();
      }
      url += '?t=' + now; //Add current time to prevent browser caching
      console.info('refreshGeoJson url: ' + url);
          this.getJson(url).when({
        ready: function(response) {
          var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
          var features = format.readFeatures(response, {
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
          });
          console.dir(features);
          console.log(features.length);
          source.addFeatures(features);
          source.changed();
        }
         });
},
    getJson: function(url) {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
          when = {},
          onload = function() {
        console.log('xhr.status onload() ' + xhr.status);
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
         console.log('getJson() xhr: ');
         console.dir(xhr);
         console.log('getJson() xhr.response: ');
         console.dir(xhr.response);
                  when.ready.call(undefined, JSON.parse(xhr.response));
            }
        if (xhr.status === 404) {
          console.log('file not found! url: ' + url);
          alert("file not found!\n" + url);
        }
          },
          onerror = function() {
            console.info('Cannot XHR ' + JSON.stringify(url));
          };
      //console.log('getJson() - retrieve file url: ' + url);
          xhr.open('GET', url, true);
          xhr.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-store');
          xhr.onload = onload;
          xhr.onerror = onerror;
          xhr.send(null);
          return {
        when: function(obj) { when.ready = obj.ready; }
        };
    }
};

var vectorLoader = function(extent, resolution, projection) {
  utils.refreshGeoJson(this);
}

var resortSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: /path-to/myFile.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
       defaultDataProjection :'EPSG:3857' 
    }),
    loader: vectorLoader,
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
  });
```

If there is a syntax problem with your geojson file, it will fail here `when.ready.call(undefined, JSON.parse(xhr.response));`.  This give you way more control over things instead of just using the url property without the vector loader function.

Comment: So I gave this a go and still no dice, I appreciate the thorough code with commenting! It logged "xhr.status onload() 0".

Comment: Since you received a 0 (zero) return code from XHR call, I would check out these posts:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825581/does-an-http-status-code-of-0-have-any-meaning   and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/http-status-code-0-what-does-this-mean-in-ms-xmlhttp

Comment: Also, check you web server log file and see if the request if making it to the server or not???