# PIVOTAL HAWQ- PXF connection is not working

Tags: ambari, cloud-foundry, hawq

We have small Hadoop-HAWQ cluster. in that, when trying to read external table.

```
prod# select * from ext_table
```

**Getting error:**

This pxf error is not letting us read external table via select query.

```
 "remote component error (0) from 'xx.xx.xx.xx:51200': couldn't connect to host (libchurl.c:852)"
```

**Tried :**

Restarted PXF via ambari and all is Green.

Any help on it would be much appreciated ?

Comment: Are you able to ping to server xx.xx.xx.xx . HAWQ returns error in the form "remote component error (http error code). 0 does not belong to any standard http error code but is a XmlHttpRequest status which has a varied number of possibilities. This appears to be a problem on the network where connection to host xx.xx.xx.xx is not possible.

Found an interesting [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26451773/3568185) sharing plethora of causes for 0 response code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like pxf-service is down in the nodes .Please make sure the pxf service is startedin all the namenodes and datanodes .Also make sure port 51200 is listening and is not bind to any other orphan process .

Please login to pxf nodes via terminal (not through ambari ) .

service pxf-service stop 
service pxf-service start

**To check for orphan process**

netstat -anp |grep 51200

kill -9 processid

Thanks
Pratheesh Nair