# IE drops all AJAX requests, only when loading site directly from startup

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs, internet-explorer

When Loading my site directly from a shortcut / commandline (i.e running `iexplore 192.168.0.1`), IE loads `https://192.168.0.1` and cancels all AJAX requests - it fails with [status code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507670/687857), resulting in a very broken site...

1. After that, hitting refresh loads the site well.
2. Navigating from an already open IE loads the site well.
3. Running `iexplore https://192.168.0.1` loads the site well.

I'm using IE 11.0.9600.17207, running in edge mode (`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`). I have URL rewrite setting on the server, redirecting HTTP to HTTPS.

Chrome and FF works fine.
I'm using angular 1.3

Is this an IE bug? Am I missing some IE compatibility setting here?

Comment: Why would you run IE from the command line? You might need to add something like `http://` to the location parameter...

Comment: When we deploy to a client, they have a shortcut on the desktop for their deployed intranet site. I use `Win+R -> iexplore 192.168.0.1` because I don't want to see the IE logo :-)

Comment: So, are you getting any console errors? Did you try adding the `http://`? Also, I'd rather see the IE icon, than having the browser open ;-)

Comment: I can't see if there are any, because when I open the dev tools in IE, it doesn't show previous errors (before it was open). Adding `http://` doesn't change anything (as it shouldn't). Adding `https://` on the other hand solves this... I'll edit the question.

Comment: Why can't you change your IE icon to something else?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs - Are you serious..? the command line is not the issue. My clients use a shortcut on their desktop.

Comment: @seldary: you're aware a desktop shortcut is different from a command line command, right? And I assume those clients aren't navigating to `129.168.0.1`? Any way, if the only problem is caused by opening the site from the command line, don't open it from the command line. Get yourself a shortcut, and assign a hotkey to it.

Comment: @Cerbrus - As I said, the commandline is not the issue. They are not the same, but have exactly the same symptoms.