# How to read json from url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working on get json from server in javascript.

i used pure javascript, jquery but i am getting status 0.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(event){
        $.getJSON('http://myhost/myapp/data.json', function(jd) {
            alert(jd);
        });
    });
});

<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Load Data" />
</body>
```

`getJSON()` block not called.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Any errors in your console ?

Comment: Does data.json contain valid JSON?

Comment: Put another argument on the getJSON call like function(error) { alert(error); } and see if it is called... then it was an error...

Comment: ...or look at your console

Comment: question! are you on the same domain? Have you checked that CORS is not blocking your request?

Comment: Can you install fiddler and see what response you are getting for that ajax call ? It could also be an cross domain issue

Comment: i checked my json content is correct and i used $.getJSON(...).fail() its called.

Comment: i got error in console 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Console is king : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 0):

Check if you allow [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on your host or if your [response was empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/http-status-code-0-what-does-this-mean-in-ms-xmlhttp)!

You might also try to use `$.ajax()`.

```
$.ajax("http://myhost/myapp/data.json", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use `jQuery.getJSON()`
`$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});`
read more from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson

Comment: It's basically the same call. OP is just using a shorthand. If the shorthand fails because the URL is incorrect or the JSON is invalid, this will fail as well. The problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: give it a try first @JeremyThille

Comment: @PatrickMutwiri, There is no need to try, the page you even link to says **This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to** to the code you have supplied, both will do exactly the same thing