# Simple AJAX not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome

I've been trying to get this piece of AJAX program to run but it won't work on Chrome or Safari. It works on Firefox, though.

```
function myFunction() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML =this.responseText;
      }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "myPage.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: what do u get in the browser's console?

Comment: are you sure you have element with id="myID"

Comment: Add the whole code, because I've tested [here](http://codepen.io/LagartoSeb/pen/EWRLaQ) and the code works.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what error or response you are getting when you try this in Chrome and Safari. Also be certain you are finding the element with the ID you're passing in. Have you tried to console.log() `this.responseText` or checked the network tab in chrome devtools to see your response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, It's the installed extensions that are messing it up!

Print the ready state and HTTP status code. You should be getting ready state 4 and status code 0 in chrome in this case.

Please read the answer by Lee in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/http-status-code-0-what-does-this-mean-for-fetch-or-xmlhttprequest/14507670)