# How is it possible to return a predefined value from a http request, if the user is offline? (Angular)

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I would like to cache some of the data, which is requested from the server. I modified the http request like this:

```
// user.ts
export class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

// inside the component:

getUsers() : Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.api+'/get-users').pipe(
        tap(users => {
            localStorage.setItem("cache_users", JSON.stringify(users));
        })
    );
}
```

How is it possible to load the users from the cache, if the request failed, because the server was unreachable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch the error thrown once the request is made and return the cache, in case that the error was caused because of the client offline state:

```
import {of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

getUsers() : Observable<User[]> {
    const url = `${this.api}/get-users`;
    return this.http.get<User[]>(url ).pipe(
        tap(users => localStorage.setItem(url , JSON.stringify(users))),
        catchError(error => {
          if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse 
             && error.status=== 0
             && !error.url){
             // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507670/5394220
             // Try to read the local storage. If the key is not present, return an empty list
             const rawJson = localStorage.getItem(url);
             return of(!!rawJson ? JSON.parse(rawJson) : []);
          }
          // 
          return throwError(error);
        })
    );
}
```

You might want to try differents approach, for example using the [window.navigator.onLine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/189457/5394220) property.

Comment: (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) is true, even in offline mode

Answer (score 2):

you can use `catchError`

```
catchError(() => of(localStorage.getItem("cache_users")));
```

---

```
getUsers() : Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.api+'/get-users').pipe(
        tap(users => {
            localStorage.setItem("cache_users", JSON.stringify(users));
        }),
        catchError(() => of(localStorage.getItem("cache_users")))
    );
}
```