# How can I get the error code and message in Angular 16 error interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I am having a difficulty in detecting the error status code and error message in Angular error interceptor:

```
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private loading: LoadingService,
        private msg: ShowMessageService
    ) { }
    intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            
            catchError((err: any) => {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.error("Error occured while calling BE API: ", err);
                this.loading.setLoading(false);
                let errorMsg = err.error.message;
                if (err.error.message !== undefined) {
                    errorMsg = err.error.message;
                } else if (err.error.ErrorMessage !== undefined) {
                    errorMsg = err.error.ErrorMessage;
                } else {
                    switch (err.status) {
                        case 0:
                            errorMsg = "Sorry for inconvenience. An error occurred during communication with the server.";
                            break;
                        case 401:
                            errorMsg = "Sorry for inconvenience, but you are not authorized for this.";
                            break;
                        //more http codes added here to handle, 404, 500, etc.
                        default:
                            errorMsg = "Sorry for inconvenience, but an error occurred during communication with the server. Please contact the administrator.";
                    }
                }
                this.msg.showErrorMsg(errorMsg);
                return of(err);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

When I use Postman, I get the following error message from backend:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Fail to handle the request."
    }
}
```

But in Angular, I can't get this error message, although in Chrome dev tools, I can see the status is 500, and `polyfills.js` print error as `net::ERR_FAILED 500 (Internal Server Error)`:

[image]

But there's no response. Here's the screenshot of response (Failed to load response data):

[image]

And when I print the error in console, I always get error code 0, for failed requests. Does Angular interceptor override the HTTP error messages from backend? What should I do to prevent this?

Comment: Sounds like your backend isn't handling CORS correctly, so details aren't exposed to the JS. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54922985/3001761