# Python request.get fails on specific site

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I just finished automate the boring stuff with python, now i'm just practicing.
I try running the code below but it fails . Other sites has no issue connecting .

Searched for other questions they say add user:agent, it works for amazon.com but not for this site .
I tried allow_redirects = False and ,verify=False too , they are not working

I am using Windows 10 , Python 3.8.5 , requests 2.24.0

my code ;

```
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
print('1')
res = requests.get('https://freida.ama-assn.org/search/list?spec=42931',headers=headers)
print('2')
print(res.status_code)
res.raise_for_status()
```

This code does not prints '2' fails at requests.get

**Error code as follows :**

```
C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User198/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/amaResidency.py
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 362, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 384, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\User198\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\User198\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\User198\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 403, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 362, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 384, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\User198\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\User198\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\User198\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User198/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/amaResidency.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(res.status_code)
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User198\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))
```

Comment: your code works for me returning a `200` http status code

Comment: may be something is wrong with the headers variable if you run it without header that will do work fine but the header varible is creating some issue

Comment: Your code is fine. It is returning 200 and printing both 1 and 2.

It could be some network issue. https://bugs.python.org/issue31122 This error is generally returned when the client tries to connect without SSL. Are you behind any proxy or some firewall?

Comment: As you can see in the last line of your error code, it states that you have an error called ```0```. This has a specific meaning. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/what-does-it-mean-when-an-http-request-returns-status-code-0) question, since it really helps to explain why you get that error in the first place.

Comment: After you guys say that it connects, i tried with my phones internet connection, it *worked* . It seems like my wifi connection is the issue but i don't know what to do :S Like i said all other sites connects succesfully  with requests.get

Answer (score 0):

So, seems like i fixed the issue .
In my case code was working via my cellphone internet but Wi-Fi connection was failing for this particular site .
I unchecked "Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver" from **Control panel => network and internet => network connections => LeftClick your connection and properties => Networking tab => Uncheck "Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver"**

Everything was checked except "microsoft network adapter multiplexor protocol"
Now "Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver" is not checked too.

This solution worked for me

Comment: update on the situation, my 'trick' was temporary, i think something wrong with the website, sometimes my code works, sometimes i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You may try ignoring SSL certificate verification using `verify = False`. It drastically reduced my count of similar ConnectionErrors.

`res = requests.get('https://freida.ama-assn.org/search/list?spec=42931', headers=headers, verify=False)`

*Note that when verify is set to False, requests will accept any TLS certificate presented by the server, and will ignore hostname mismatches and/or expired certificates, which will make your application vulnerable to man-in-the-middle (MitM) attacks.*