# C# .NET HttpClient POST returns an empty response sometimes

Tags: .net, httpclient

I am using HttpClient to send a POST request to an external API and I know I'm sending the correct payload and headers and everything because it works sometimes but other times it returns an empty string response. It always returns a 200 status code. Changing it to asynchronous is not an option so my question is, how do I run this synchronously and reliably get a response back?

This is the method that I've used in a number of other places in my application for GETs and POSTs and it works perfectly fine every time:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("url")
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);

var input = new {json object};

var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input, serializerSettings);
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var result = client.PostAsync("api/Create", data).Result;
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var jsonStringResult = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(jsonStringResult);
    // response is null....sometimes
}
```

Other methods that I've tried from scouring other forum posts and blogs:

```
var postTask = client.PostAsync("api/Create", data);
postTask.Wait();
var result = postTask.Result;
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var jsonTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    jsonTask.Wait();
    var jsonStringResult = jsonTask.Result;
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(jsonStringResult);
    // response is null....sometimes
}
```

and

```
var result = client.PostAsync("api/Create", data).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var jsonStringResult = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(jsonStringResult);
    // response is null....sometimes
}
```

and

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.Headers.Add("X-Authorization", "Bearer" + authToken);

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

dataStream.Close();
response.Close();

var responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(responseFromServer);
// resonseObj is null...sometimes
```

All four methods work some of the time but I need this to be more reliable. Deadlocks are not a concern at this time.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you use Fiddler (or some other network trace tool) to confirm that the body is being returned from the server. There might be nothing wrong with your client.

Comment: Why is async not an option?

Comment: Its a windows form app that communicates with a microcontroller and executes a bunch of actions in a specific order. It took a lot of effort to get everything working just right. I tried running this piece asynchronously and it threw everything else out of wack and still didn't work any better than the other methods above.

Comment: I've run into a very similar problem. In my case, the code works reliably and I got proper responses when it's run on various Windows 10 machines, but fails most of the time when run on a Windows Server. Have you had any progress solving it?

Comment: @Avi on windows server is it run ever successfully? after how many tries it gets fail?

Comment: @Saeed, it's inconsistent. Sometimes it takes 2 or 3 tries before it works. Sometimes 5 or 6. I'd estimate that it works 30% of the time.

Comment: @Avi It always return 200? or in case on not working return other statuses like 500?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad, when it works, it's status code 200. When it fails, it's status 0.

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad, here's a screenshot of a test program I made that tries to make the call repeatedly in a loop three times, and outputs the status code each time. You can see that it tried 3 times, and failed each one. Then it tried again 3 times, and failed again. Then it tried again, and succeeded on the second try. https://ibb.co/WgxVk15

Comment: Maybe this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/what-does-it-mean-when-an-http-request-returns-status-code-0

Comment: Do you also get inconsistent results on Postman?

Comment: I suggest you extend the request timeout, If it doesn't work and you aren't able to debug API code, try using network packet tracers or test API using Postman

Comment: @tw3399 you're not likely to get a good answer until you eliminate all of your middleware, proxies, reverse proxies, etc. You need to work with a very basic client located as "close" as possible to the API in question and see what happens (e.g. `curl` with as few network hops as possible).

Comment: @EmreUtkuSolak, no. Making the request with Postman consistently works fine. As does browsing the site regularly with a browser.

Comment: It also seems to work fine when using curl.

Comment: @EmreUtkuSolak and SaeedEsmaeelinejad, I finally got it all resolved. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment above, I noted that I was having the same occasional empty response issue, but I finally figured out what was happening and got my code working. There were 2 issues I had to address:

1. My user-agent header. I was using a user-agent that included a bunch of various elements, something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36`, and when I changed it to just `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)` everything started working more consistently. (I was having the empty responses on a Windows Server environment, so you might have to adjust this to match the user-agent string to exactly your own environment.)
2. I had used Postman to test my calls and took the generated code that it produced, but when using Fiddler I discovered that there was a header Postman was sending that was not being outputted in their generated code. Specifically: `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`. So naturally, it hadn't been included it in my code.

When I modified these two aspects of my http request code, it consistently worked without any empty responses. However, just to note, one more thing had to be adjusted after adding the `accept-encoding` header. The response was being compressed, so I had to specify that the HttpClient automatically decompress the response. My final HttpRequest initialization code looked like this:

```
    Dim HttpClient = New HttpClient(New HttpClientHandler With {.UseCookies = False, .AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate})
    Try
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)")
        HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authority", "https://blahblah")
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")  
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("cookie", CookieVar)
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("origin", "https://blahblah")
        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("referer", "https://blahblah")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

A final note: once I specified the AutomaticDecompression properties, using Fiddler I discovered that the Accept-Encoding header was added automatically to the call, so the actual line that specified it could be taken out. I left it in above just to show what I was talking about.

Also, to explain the `.UseCookies = False` line in the HttpClientHandler, see [here](https://d-fens.ch/2016/12/27/howto-set-cookie-header-on-defaultrequestheaders-of-httpclient/).