# Azure EventGrid moving the Events to Dead-letter queue without retry

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

Azure EventGrid moving the Events to Dead-letter queue without retry.

But I am seeing the following reason:

"deadLetterReason": "UndeliverableDueToClientError"
"deliveryAttempts": 1
"lastDeliveryOutcome": "Probation"
"lastHttpStatusCode": 0

Please help me to understand the dead letter reason attributes.

**deliveryAttempts = 1**
Why EventGrid is not retying when Destination is put in probation? Can we do any config settings to ask the EventGrid to retry before moving the Events to Dead-letter queue.

**lastHttpStatusCode = 0** What's this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The concept of Event Grid **dead letter** explained as it moves event to the dead letter queue when the destination like storage account is unable to send the **Save events that cannot be delivered to storage event in a certain time period** or exceeded the number of limits.
- As shown in the below image In Create Event Subscription select **Additional features** and **Enable dead lettering** to catch any events **that are not delivered successfully to the subscribers** . This will send any undelivered events to the specified storage account

[image]

```
lastHttpStatusCode = 0
```

*As mentioned in the [Document](https://technicqa.com/what-does-a-status-code-of-0-mean/#:%7E:text=An%20HTTP%20response%20code%20of%200%20indicates%20that,request%20failed%20to%20execute%20within%20a%20specified%20time.)  The HTTP response code of 0 indicates that the request was cancelled. It can happen because of timeout, abortion on the request.  It indicates the request failed to execute within a specified time. Here 0 indicates the no status code was returned by destination.
You can also refer the same issue [Status code 0 of Http Request.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872206/what-does-it-mean-when-an-http-request-returns-status-code-0)

```
  delivery attempts = 1
```

- Here delivery attempts 1 indicates the event grid has attempted to deliver the events only once.

```
    Undeliverable due To Client error
```

- It indicates mainly client-side network error in destination.
- You can set [Dead letter retry policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery) by following MS Document.
  As shown in below image set **configure retry polices** ok and the max delivery attempts must be 1 to 30 and even you can set  **EVENT SUBSCRIPTION EXPIRATION TIME**
  [image]

Dead letter MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-schedule) for reference